# Failed to build newlib4.4 for ARM in WSL2 Linux x86_64

Tags: linux, make, cross-compilation

I am working on an embedded RTOS system for ARM platform, it is using newlib-3.1.
Now I am trying to support newlib-4.4 for the system in WSL2 (Ubuntu-20.04.6 for X86_64).

The cross-compiler for ARM is also self-built, `arm-none-xoseabi`.
To build the newlib4.4, I configured and built with following commands.

```
../newlib-4.4.0.20231231/configure --target=arm-none-xoseabi --prefix=/home/test/develop/newlib44/build --enable-threads=posix --enable-newlib-multithread --enable-tls --with-multilib-list=aprofile,mprofile

make -j12
```

```
checking for arm-none-xoseabi-gcc... arm-none-xoseabi-cc -B/home/test/develop/newlib44/newlib_arm/arm-none-xoseabi/newlib/ -isystem /home/test/develop/newlib44/newlib_arm/arm-none-xoseabi/newlib/targ-include -isystem /home/test/develop/newlib44/newlib-4.4.0.20231231/newlib/libc/include -B/home/test/develop/newlib44/newlib_arm/arm-none-xoseabi/libgloss/arm -L/home/test/develop/newlib44/newlib_arm/arm-none-xoseabi/libgloss/libnosys -L/home/test/develop/newlib44/newlib-4.4.0.20231231/libgloss/arm
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/test/develop/newlib44/newlib_arm/arm-none-xoseabi/newlib':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details
make[1]: *** [Makefile:8448: configure-target-newlib] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/test/develop/newlib44/newlib_arm'
make: *** [Makefile:879: all] Error 2
```

I am not sure if I can ask question about `newlib` here, if not, where should I post the question?